# Adding sum of all odd numbers with range JAVA

Tags: java, sum

I have a problem, I have the correct(PART 1) and incorrect code (PART 2). I cant figure out why the incorrect code is incorrect.

the

```
static int sum = 0
```

part is the incorrect part of the code in PART 2. If that line of code is moved to the same location at PART 1. The code works.

if the range is from 10 to 20. PART 2 outputs an incorrect sum of 111. The sum should be 75. There are 3 possible combinations to get 111.

```
18 + 18 + correct sum
17 +19 + correct sum
16 + 20 + correct sum
```

Im guessing PART 2 passes through 18 + 18? but how?!

PART 1 Correct Code

```
ublic class SumOddRange {

public static boolean isOdd(int number){
    if (number <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return number % 2 != 0;
    
}

public static int sumOdd(int start, int end){
    if ( (end < start) || (start < 0) || (end < 0) ){
        return -1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = start; i<=end; i++){
        if (isOdd(i)){
            sum +=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
    
}
```

PART 2 INCORRECT CODE

```
public class SumOddRange {



public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
    if((number > 0) && (number % 2 != 0)) {

        return true;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }
}

static  int startOne = 0;
static int sum = 0;
public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
    if ((end >= start) && (end > 0) && (start > 0)) {

        for (startOne = start; startOne <= end; startOne++) {
            if (isOdd(startOne)) {
                sum += startOne;


            }
        }

        return sum;
    } else

        return -1;
}
```

Comment: In the second snippet `sum` is a static variable, meaning it keeps the value between calls of `sumOdd`. In first part it is a local variable that resets in each method call.

Comment: Shouldn't you set `sum` to zero before your loop in `sumOdd`?

Comment: I still dont understand what static is. I am going to search it up.

Comment: @GrantLee I tested the program and it returned 75. Maybe you just forgot to reset the value of sum as khelwood mentioned or If you have created multiple objects of the class the keyword "static" might be causing an issue. It would be nice if you attach the main method as well.

Comment: Note that negative numbers can be odd or even too!

Comment: @JayanPaliwal the website I was using to check my answer creates multiple objects to check my answer. That is why I was so confused. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `static` variables.

**What does `static` mean?**

[image]

After creating a class, you can create *instances* (also called *objects*) of this class. This is what happens, when you use a command like

`SumOddRange a = new SumOddRange();`

`SumOddRange b = new SumOddRange();`

As you probably know, there are methods and variables in a class. These methods and classes can be seperated into

- Class methods and variables
- Object methods and variables (object variables are most often called *attributes*)

This means that some methods and variables do belong to the class, so all the instances of this class share this variable or method. This is what `static` is used for. So if the class in the image above has a static attribute named `staticAttributeName`, `a.staticAttributeName` and `b.staticAttributeName` have to be the same.

If a variable isn't static, this variable is not shared by the instances. All instances have their own *instance* of this variable. So although their name is the same, the values saved in the variables doen't have to be the same. So if the class in the image above has a non-static attribute named `attributeName`, `a.attributeName` and `b.attributeName` doesn't have to be the same.

**An example:**

```
public class Add {
    public static int sum = 0;

    public static void addOne() {
        sum = sum + 1;
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Add a = new Add();
        Add b = new Add();

        a.addOne();
        b.addOne();
        System.out.println("a " + a.sum);
        System.out.println("b " + b.sum);   
    }
}
```

As you can see, the variable `sum` is static. This means that `a.sum` and `b.sum` are the same. In the main-method, we are calling the method `addOne` two times, so the two outputs are "a 2" and "b 2".

```
public class Add {
    public int sum = 0;

    public void addOne() {
        sum = sum + 1;
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Add a = new Add();
        Add b = new Add();

        a.addOne();
        b.addOne();
        b.addOne();
        System.out.println("a " + a.sum);
        System.out.println("b " + b.sum);   
    }
}
```

We now have a non-static variable `sum` in the class `Add`.

- a: We are calling the method `addOne` one time, so the first output is "a 1".
- b: The method `addOne` is called two times, so the output is "b 2".

**Solving the problem**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumOddRange s = new SumOddRange();    //Using class given in PART2 of question
        SumOddRange t = new SumOddRange();
        System.out.println(s.sumOdd(10,20));
        System.out.println(s.sumOdd(10,20));
    }
}
```

This class produces the outputs `75` and `150`. This is the case, because `s` and `t` use the same variable `sum`, so the first time, the sum is correct, but the second calculation returns `75+sumOdd(10,20) = 75+75 = 150` as the result.

As we now know, the main problem is that the variable(s) are `static`. This brings up the idea to just use non-static variables, which is the best idea here:

```
public class SumOddRange {

    public boolean isOdd(int number) {
        if((number > 0) && (number % 2 != 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int startOne = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    public int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
        sum = 0;
        if ((end >= start) && (end > 0) && (start > 0)) {
            for (startOne = start; startOne <= end; startOne++) {
                if (isOdd(startOne)) {
                    sum += startOne;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }        
    }
}
```

Another option is to just reset the variable `sum` before actually calculating the sum. The disadvantage of this approach is that you will not be able to access earlier results anymore:

```
static  int startOne = 0;
static int sum = 0;
public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
    sum = 0;
    if ((end >= start) && (end > 0) && (start > 0)) {
        for (startOne = start; startOne <= end; startOne++) {
            if (isOdd(startOne)) {
                sum += startOne;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }        
}
```